# Jet Engine Repeater Fields

Tags: html, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields, jet-engine

I have a problem with the repeater widget ( jet engine plugin )
I need to display media field types like dynamic to display the media in all custom post type
depending on what the picture uploaded in the custom field

So when I want to display I see %field-name% I need to put the field name in between this %___%
to dynamic display in all custom post type

I will attach screenshots of what I see when I try.

[This is what I need to do to make the field dynamic, but it's not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnng8.png)
[This is way displayed but it's not dynamic, which means displaying this picture in all custom posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n49od.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.